# translate api to PHP get format

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I'm a beginner in web design 
and I was trying this API
http://docs.imagga.com/

and it mention that auto-tagging need to use get request
and it give this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/E2zEUrm.png]   ->  it's a screen shot picture

but I have no idea how to send request

(after I saw the below answer given by Barmar)
I have tried to type this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.imagga.com/v1/tagging',         
    type: "GET",                          
    data: { url: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Mountain-bike-racing.jpg'} ,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", " Basic my key");
    },
    success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }

});  });
```

but it comes to show that

- XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.imagga.com/v1/tagging. No 'Access-Contro
  l-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

thanks for your help

Comment: for a start you need the full domain included in url for the api. The docs are assuming you already know that part and keeping the display short for ease of reading. Look for something like `base URL`

Comment: Let me ask a sily question… isn't it a cloud api？ I can just send to their server to analyze the image and it will response a json file？

Comment: WARNING: My anti-virus blocks http://docs.imagga.com/.

Comment: i think it's a mistake, it is a normal website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.imagga.com/v1/tagging',         
        type: "GET",                          
        data: { url: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Mountain-bike-racing.jpg',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic YourAPIKey");
        },
        success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

You use the `data:` parameter to set URL parameters in `GET` requests. To implement authentication, you have to add an `Authorization` header, this is done using the Javascript `setRequestHeader` method on the XHR object.

Comment: I haven't used pastie.org before. Is there some way to run the script from there? If not, what was the point of posting the code there instead of adding to your question?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try to run it? I don't know if it makes a difference, but you have an extra space before `Basic` in the authorization header.

Comment: ahahahah,sorry for that....I just don't know I can add into my question......and the error is that "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.imagga.com/v1/tagging. No 'Access-Contro
l-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Comment: Click the "edit" link below the question to update it. Anyway, that error is the normal result of violating the AJAX same-origin policy. You need to do the API call from a server script, not from the browser. If you do it in the browser, the user can get your API key, which is supposed to be secret.

Comment: BTW, I hope you didn't post your real API key in the pastie. If you did, you should change it.

Comment: ohoh thank for your suggestion :) , I will try to modify this code

Comment: THX a lot , I have figured out this problem by sending post request to server side's php ,and then the php file use get method to send request.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this question

the index.html file looks like

```
 $("button").click(function(){
$.get('post_url.php', function(rep){
```

and the post_url.php looks like

```
 function send_post($url){
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Authorization: Basic key \r\n'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

return $result;
};
```